# How do I animate text in bootstrap header like so

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

On this demo bootstrap template:

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/

When you scroll down the title text 'Start Bootstrap' shrinks and changes colour.

How is this done? I've tried to work it out in the code - I know it's using Bootstrap's affix and I can get it to that the text resizes - I just don't know how the animated transition between font sizes works.

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you have tried so far that isn't quite working?

Comment: Rather than actually build anything, I've been dissecting that template to try and work out how it's been done.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a website where you ask what you need. You should ask something after have trying to do it.... But for your question, you should googelize about css animation and transition, it's funny...

Comment: If you wanna look at the repo that powers it... https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-creative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine they're doing something like this...

```js
/* Important bit... */
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $nav = $('.navbar-brand');
    
    if ($this.scrollTop() > 100) {
       $nav.addClass('small');
    } else {
       $nav.removeClass('small');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200?text=scroll) repeat;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: all 1s ease; /* ... other important bit */
}

/* this bit's important too... */
.small { 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f05f40;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
```